# Why is my href not being rendered on @html.Sitecore().Field(link)

Tags: mvc

Here is my code:

```
<div class="btn-lg">@Html.Sitecore().Field("Feature Link", Model.Item, new { text = @Html.Sitecore().Field("Feature Link Button Text", Model.Item)})</div>
```

here is what it is rendering:

```
<a  Apply ></a>
```

Answer (score 3):

### Original problem was data related. Answer below explains how to achieve same thing in cleaner (and possibly safer) way

I guess Sitecore cannot handle nested `@Html.Sitecore().Field()` code.

Try this code:

```
<div class="btn-lg">
    @Html.Sitecore().BeginField("Feature Link", Model.Item)
    @Html.Sitecore().Field("Feature Link Button Text", Model.Item)
    @Html.Sitecore().EndField()
</div>
```

Comment: I tried that, and I thank you for your help, but now I don't get a link at all, but the text.

Comment: Actually the fault was my own, I did not specify a link, now that I have I believe this is working.thank you

Comment: Can we close this question, or update the answer to reflect that the problem was data related and not code related. If you had a link, the original code would probably have worked OK. Although Marek's is safer.